# MySQL - make "Update" a permanent change to a table?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I have two tables - "Horses" and "Results". "Horses" lists a bunch of information about each horse, including a spot called "LTE", which totals from an "Earnings" field from the "Results" table. "Results" listed all the results of recent horse shows. I use the following code to calculate LTE -

```
UPDATE horses 
SET horses.LTE = ( SELECT SUM(results.earnings) 
FROM results WHERE horses.hname=results.hname )
```

Which works wonderfully - it updates the LTE column. However...I have to run this code EVERY time I add new data to the "Results" table. I will be adding data month for...well, pretty much ever.

I don't want to have to run this code every time. Is there a way to make the code "permanent," in a sense that the LTE field KNOWS it just calculates whenever new information is added? Or does MySQL not work this way?

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2b00b) a peek at my tables with some data in them.

Comment: Why do you want to keep that (redundant) information in your horses table? Can't you just calculate it on the fly?

Comment: @Pevara it's not really effective to calculate such things on the fly, especially if it's rather frequently queried value

Comment: @StanMcGeek that heavily depends on the (amount of) data and the way in which it is used (read vs write). Denormalizing your data can indeed be useful, but I'm no fan of premature optimization. So that's why I asked the question, it could very well be the wrong strategy in this case.

Comment: @Pevara oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood you. This is a very valid point

Comment: @Pervara The information isn't redundant, it's part of how we track how "useful" a horse is. Every show it competes in it adds more value to the horse. It would be easier on our end just to upload the Results data every month/twice monthly and let the horse table autocalculate LTE

Comment: Technically speaking your data is not fully normalized (the score is stored in the horses table, while it can also be aggregated from the results table). Therefor it is strictly speaking redundant  information. Usually that is a bad thing (you have to maintain your data in multiple places, or you risk getting inconsistent data), though it is sometimes done for performance reasons. Seen that you appear to have few write operations and a lot of read operations it may be a valid strategy in your case. As you have noticed it adds some complexity though, so that is why I questioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` to update your table:

```
-- trigger for INSERT (new rows on table result).
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER ins_result AFTER INSERT ON results
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE horses SET horses.LTE = (
            SELECT SUM(results.earnings) FROM results WHERE horses.hname = results.hname
        );
    END;
|

-- trigger for UPDATE (changed rows on table result).
CREATE TRIGGER upd_result AFTER UPDATE ON results
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE horses SET horses.LTE = (
            SELECT SUM(results.earnings) FROM results WHERE horses.hname = results.hname
        );
    END;
|

-- trigger for DELETE (removed rows on table result).
CREATE TRIGGER del_result AFTER DELETE ON results
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE horses SET horses.LTE = (
            SELECT SUM(results.earnings) FROM results WHERE horses.hname = results.hname
        );
    END;
|
```

---

Another solution could be a [`VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html):

```
CREATE VIEW v_horses AS 
    SELECT h.*, SUM(r.earnings) AS 'LTE' 
    FROM horses h INNER JOIN results r ON h.hname = r.hname
    GROUP BY h.hname;
```

With the created `VIEW` you can get the information about the horses with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM v_horses;
```

In your case you doesn't use a `DECIMAL` column. So you have to convert the `VARCHAR` column to `SUM` the earnings. So in your case you have to use the following `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW v_horses AS 
    SELECT h.*, SUM(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(r.earnings, ',', ''), '$', '') AS DECIMAL)) AS 'LTE' 
    FROM horses h INNER JOIN results r ON h.hname = r.hname 
    GROUP BY h.hname;

-- for a specific year (like 2017)
CREATE VIEW v_horses AS 
    SELECT h.*, SUM(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(r.earnings, ',', ''), '$', '') AS DECIMAL)) AS 'LTE' 
    FROM horses h INNER JOIN results r ON h.hname = r.hname
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(r.`Date`, '%c/%e/%y'), '%Y') = 2017
    GROUP BY h.hname;

-- grouped by year (so you can use WHERE on the VIEW):
CREATE VIEW v_horses AS 
    SELECT h.*, SUM(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(r.earnings, ',', ''), '$', '') AS DECIMAL)) AS 'LTE',
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(r.`Date`, '%c/%e/%y'), '%Y') AS 'year'
    FROM horses h INNER JOIN results r ON h.hname = r.hname
    GROUP BY h.hname, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(r.`Date`, '%c/%e/%y'), '%Y');
```

> **Note:** In case of using this `VIEW` you have to remove the column `LTE` from table `horses`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I get the following error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '|' at line 8 "

Comment: Make sure your are using `DELIMITER |` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: I am, and I get the same error. Occasionally the error changes to "This version does not support multiple triggers". Out of curiosity, what does the "view" option do? Does it create a column, since I'll have removed the LTE?

Comment: I think view is exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Comment: See the updated `VIEW`. In your case you can't simply `SUM` the earnings because you are using a `VARCHAR` (or `TEXT`) column.

Comment: Yes - this is exactly what I wanted! One last quick (I hope) question - say I only wanted a SUM of the earnings when Results.Date = 2017. I have that field - silly me - set up as a TEXT as well, and the format is mm/dd/yy.

Comment: added to the answer. there are some possible solutions. I add more later.

Comment: @OP Note that the "View" solution does exactly what I suggested, and calculates the score on the fly. It may come with a performance hit, since the scores are no longer cached (you could "materialize" your views, but that's a whole different story), but it will make your data normalized again, no more redundancy and risk of getting inconsistent data, so +1 for that!

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't work that way. But you can achieve such functionality by using [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). For example, you can update your sum each time there's insert in respective table (and/or update), this way you will always have your sum 'cached' and you can recalculate if needed.

If you want a bit more analytics on sum changes, you can follow [this pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/AccountingNarrative.html), I think it will be helpful